# how to reuse merge request pipeline coverage to be used in default branch pipeline by not collecting coverage again on default branch after mergingPR?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, testing

I have to run the code coverage pipeline again after merging the PR because, in the merge request, it shows diff code coverage from the default branch and I do not want to run the code coverage pipeline again on the default branch.

how to reuse merge request pipeline coverage in GitLab to be used in the default branch pipeline by not collecting coverage again on the default branch pipeline after merging the merge request because merging creates a merge commit which runs a pipeline which I do not have to remove?